# Suggestion needed for Java Program

Tags: java

I have created a class in Java named Farm which contains a list of animals(cow,pig and chick).
myFarm is an array of object of Farm class containing objects of NamedCow,pig and chick class.

my sample code goes here:

```
import java.util.*;

class Farm 

{

   private ArrayList< Animal >  myFarm;

   Farm() 

   { 

      myFarm=new ArrayList<Animal>();

      myFarm.add(new NamedCow("cow","Elsie","moo"));

      myFarm.add(new Chick("chick","cheep","cluck"));

      myFarm.add(new Pig("pig","oink"));

   }

   public void animalSounds(){

          Animal temp;

          for(int i = 0; i < myFarm.size(); i++){

             temp = myFarm.get(i);

             System.out.println(temp.getType() + " goes " + temp.getSound());

          }

          NamedCow named = (NamedCow)myFarm.get(0);

          System.out.println(named.getName());

       }

   }
```

I have not understand one line in my code: NamedCow named = (NamedCow)myFarm.get(0);
here what is the meaning of the NamedCow enclosed within parentheses in the right side. Cn anyone please tell me??

Comment: Wait, you "write" code you don't understand? Smells fishy. `NamedCow named = (NamedCow)myFarm.get(0);` gets the first Object from the List myFarm and casts it to `NamedCow`.

Comment: paste your code completely

Comment: NamedCow is a class somewhere declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just Type casting.
By writing `myFarm.get(0);` you will get the first index of `Arraylist` of type `Animal` by default. And you are assigning the value to an object of type `NamedCow`. So you need to cast the value explicitly to `NamedCow`.

In the complete code, `NamedCow` may be the super class of `Animal`. Hence a super class (`NamedCow`) variable can hold a sub class (`Animal`) object, which is a rule of inheritance in Java.

Answer (score 4):

`myFarm` is an `ArrayList<Animal>`.

In the line

```
NamedCow named = (NamedCow)myFarm.get(0);
```

You're assuming that the object in the first index in the `ArrayList` is of *type* `NamedCow`, based on that assumption, you're *casting* the object from `Animal` to `NamedCow`.

The cast inserts a *runtime* check that `named` is assigned a `NamedCow`, note that if that's **not** the case, a *runtime* exception will be thrown.

I highly recommend you to go through a tutorial about [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to better understand that since it's really the basic of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use Instance Of operator to check whether the object you are getting is named cow or pig or chick 
based on that do whatever you have to do

Use Debugger & check what is the first Object you have in MyFarm ArrayList Of Animals